# Hash of Hashes of Arrays in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to implement Hash of Hashes of Arrays in Java and thought it would be nice if I will use anonymous blah blah(i forgot the exact term/I dont know how to call it).

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String[]>> teams = 
    new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String[]>>(){{
        put("east", new HashMap<String, String[]>(){{
            put("atlantic", new String[] { "bkn", "bos", "phi","tor", "ny" });
            put("central", new String[] { "chi", "cle", "det", "ind", "mil" });
            put("southeast", new String[] { "atl", "cha", "mia", "orl", "wsh" });
        }});
        put("west", new HashMap<String, String[]>(){{
            put("northwest", new String[] { "den", "min", "okc", "por", "utah" });
            put("pacific", new String[] { "gs", "lac", "lal", "phx", "sac" });
            put("southwest", new String[] { "dal", "hou", "mem", "no", "sa" });
        }});
    }};
```

My question is if there is a another way to implement taking readability into consideration or completely perhaps completely change the implementation?
I know java is not the right tool but my boss told me to do so.
Also, please let me know of the right term. TIA

Comment: Did you mean `anonymous inner classes`?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to put this one on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @durron597 I'm about to do that but I would like to know alternatives. I will update my question, thanks.

Comment: @SJuan76 Im not sure Im leaning toward anonymous object. Could someone confirm SJuan76's answer? thanks!

Comment: The main thing I would do differently here (I don't really want to make this an answer, but I will if you like it a lot) is to store these cities in a file or, even better, some sort of SQL database. That way if it changes you don't have to change your application's source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as we're not caring about run speed, why not use a language designed to express tiered data structures like JSON? JAVA has great external library support for it ...

Gson to the rescue!

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    HashMap teams = 
    new Gson().fromJson(
        "{'east' : { 'atlantic'  : ['bkn', 'bos', 'phi','tor', 'ny']," +
        "            'central'   : ['chi', 'cle', 'det', 'ind', 'mil']," +
        "            'southeast' : ['atl', 'cha', 'mia', 'orl', 'wsh']}," +
        " 'west' : { 'northwest' : ['den', 'min', 'okc', 'por', 'utah']," +
        "            'pacific'   : ['gs', 'lac', 'lal', 'phx', 'sac']," +
        "            'southwest' : ['dal', 'hou', 'mem', 'no', 'sa']}}",
        HashMap.class
    );
```

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: I finally decided to use Gson together with a json file (suggested by @durron597)

Answer (score 2):

Using a helper method

```
private void addTeams(String area, String codes) {
    String[] areas = area.split("/");
    Map<String, String[]> map = teams.get(areas[0]);
    if (map == null) teams.put(areas[0], map = new HashMap<String, String[]>());
    map.put(areas[1], codes.split(", ?"));
}

Map<String, Map<String, String[]>> teams = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String[]>>();{
    addTeams("east/atlantic", "bkn, bos, phi, tor, ny");
    addTeams("east/central", "chi, cle, det, ind, mil");
    addTeams("east/southeast", "atl, cha, mia, orl, wsh");
    addTeams("west/northwest", "den, min, okc, por, utah");
    addTeams("west/pacific", "gs, lac, lal, phx, sac");
    addTeams("west.southwest", "dal, hou, mem, no, sa");
}
```

---

You can replace

```
new String[] { "bkn", "bos", "phi","tor", "ny" }
```

with

```
"bkn,bos,phi,tor,ny".split(",");
```

Comment: I would not recommend this. Its adding extra work, for very little benefit.

Comment: It will slow your start up by a few micro-seconds which is rarely imprtant even in low trading latency systems.

Comment: I don't like this shortcut because it's more prone to typos. `"foo,bar.baz".split(",");` will compile and fail at runtime while `new String[]{"foo", "bar". "baz"};` will raise a compiler error. Not worth the few saved keystrokes.

Comment: Why not use varargs instead? `private void addTeams(String area, String... codes)`; :)

Comment: @atamanroman both `"foo, bar.bar"` and `"foo", "bar.bar"` both compile.  You could use varargs, but it would be longer to type for little advantage.

Comment: Well, `.` instead of `,` is a typo, `"bar.baz"` instead of `"bar", "baz"`is just wrong.

Comment: @atamanroman Obviously you wouldn't pick a separator which appears in the content. It can be anything you like.